# Combine two MySQL queries to display one unique value and an AVG value for each column

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Is there a way to combine two MySQL queries to display one unique value and an AVG value for each column?
Such as in this query:

```
SELECT `price`, `cost`, `shipping` 
FROM `orders` 
WHERE `year` = 2019 AND `product_id` = 5 AND `order_id` = 77 
LIMIT 1
```

**WITH**

```
SELECT AVG(`price`), AVG(`cost`), AVG(`shipping`) 
FROM `orders` 
WHERE `year` = 2019 AND `product_id` = 5
```

I've been playing with unions and joins but I'm not finding a way to return this data in the same query. (I can make two separate queries and put the resulting data side-by-side, but I'd prefer to do it with one query if possible.)

Any ideas?

Comment: please provide sample data and expected output

Comment: GMB's answer put me on the right track to get it sorted out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since both queries return just one record, you could just turn them to subqueries and `CROSS JOIN` them :

```
SELECT a.price, a.cost, a.shipping, avg.price, avg.cost, avg.shipping 
FROM 
    ( 
        SELECT `price`, `cost`, `shipping` 
        FROM `orders` 
        WHERE `year` = 2019 AND `product_id` = 5 AND `order_id` = 77 
        LIMIT 1 
    ) a
    CROSS JOIN ( 
        SELECT AVG(`price`) price, AVG(`cost`) cost, AVG(`shipping`) shipping 
        FROM `orders` 
        WHERE `year` = 2019 AND `product_id` = 5 
    ) avg
```

The purpose of the `LIMIT 1` clause in the first subquery is unclear : since there is no `ORDER BY`, it is unpredictable which record will be returned if more than one matches.

Here is an alternative approach using conditional aggregation (if several record exist with order id `77`, the maximum value of each column will be displayed) :

```
SELECT
    MAX(CASE WHEN `order_id` = 77 THEN `price` END) price,
    MAX(CASE WHEN `order_id` = 77 THEN `cost` END) cost,
    MAX(CASE WHEN `order_id` = 77 THEN `shipping` END) shipping,
    AVG(`price`) avg_price, 
    AVG(`cost`) avg_cost,
    AVG(`shipping`) avg_shipping
FROM `orders`
WHERE `year` = 2019 AND `product_id` = 5
```

Comment: Thanks @GMB ! - I'm sure I'll use the CROSS JOIN function in the future; I'm still rather new to MySQL. With your ideas I was able get that working, which displayed it in columns, and then I figured out how I could adapt that sub-query structure to use UNION ALL (instead of CROSS JOIN) which puts the data on the next row vs. separate columns.